# Show that $tr(x x^T) \geq tr(U^T x x^T U)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that $tr(x x^T) \geq tr(U^T x x^T U)$, such that $U^T U = I_k$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $U \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times k}$.

This question popped into my head and is related to another problem I am solving. It may seem elementary but I can't seem to come up with a way to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\text{tr}(x x^T)=\Vert x\Vert^2$$
and $$\text{tr}(U^Tx x^TU)=\Vert U^T x\Vert^2$$
Now since $\Vert U^T x\Vert\le\Vert U\Vert\cdot\Vert x\Vert$ you only need to show that $\Vert U\Vert\le1$ which is evident from $U^T U=I_k$.